# Firebase - What are the ports my server is using?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Due to an API I use to manage payments, I need Firebase use a port number lesser than 5 digits (up to 9999). Otherwise the API will fail. Is there a way where I can restrict Firebase port numbers? How can I see what ports are being used?

Note that I am using cloud functions to call the API directly from Firebase.

Comment: It's not clear at all to me what you mean by "restrict Firebase port numbers".  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  Are you just referring to Cloud Functions, or are you also talking about some other Firebase product?

Comment: Hi, I want to know if my firebase app uses 5 digit port number. if yes, then I want to restrict it to use just four. Makes sense?

Comment: And yes, I am talking specially about Cloud Functions.

Comment: I'm still not clear at all what you mean.  Cloud Functions only ever receives HTTP requests on port 80 and HTTPS requests on 443.  These are the defaults and can't be changed.  I can't imagine that you'd observe anything different when the function is deployed.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that was the confirmation I was looking for. When you create a nodejs server locally you can set any port number you want, like 'localhost:44300', in this cases, the 3party API I am using will reject any request. I wanted to make sure in Firebase this is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Functions only ever receives HTTP requests on port 80 and HTTPS requests on 443. These are the defaults and can't be changed. I can't imagine that you'd observe anything different when the function is deployed.

Comment: Is there any official documentation confirming this? I couldn't find any. We would like to be able to disable port 80, but as said that "can't be changed" it seems.